# Dropbox: shared wedding photos & someone elses photos

Tags: dropbox, file-sharing

A photographer shared all the photos of wedding with daughter, who shared them with me.  It appears that he also shared several other events, which I would like to remove and I don't/shouldn't want them and they are eating up my storage space. Anything I can do to eliminate them from my dropbox without involving everyone else?

Comment: It might be better to contact the photographer and have him separate the photos.

Answer (score 1):

In the web-client, right click the folder and go to `shared folder options`. Here you can `leave folder`.